# Adding EventHandler To ImageView contained in a Label

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, eventhandler, mouseclick-event

I have recently started exploring Java FX and want to create a custom label which will have an ImageView inside it.

This is the code for my custom label.

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/remove.png"), 20, 20, true, true);
ImageView removeImageView = new ImageView(image);

Label customLabel = new Label(labelText, removeImageView);
customLabel.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
```

This is how my custom label looks.

[image]

Now I want to add a mouse click EventHandler to the ImageView. This is my code for handling the mouse clicks.

```
removeImageView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Imageview Clicked");
      }
    });
```

But when I am clicking on the `cross` image, the event is not getting captured.

I experimented a bit and tried to add an EventHandler to the `customLabel`. The label was able to capture the mouse click.

It seems to me that I am facing this issue because the ImageView is contained within the Label. What I want to know is, is this a limitation to JFX or is there any alternative way to achieve this functionality. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why this would not work. Where do you set the event handler?

Comment: @Sedrick I have set it just below the line: `ImageView removeImageView = new ImageView(image);`

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be a consequence of fixing [JDK-8117199](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8117199). The [fix](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.1/master/rt/rev/9b8f4e1097d8) added the following to `LabeledSkinBase#updateChildren()`:

```
// RT-19851 Only setMouseTransparent(true) for an ImageView.  This allows the button
// to be picked regardless of the changing images on top of it.
if (graphic instanceof ImageView) {
    graphic.setMouseTransparent(true);
}
```

As you can see, when the graphic of a `Labeled` control is an `ImageView` it is set to be mouse transparent. A workaround would be to set the mouse transparency of the `ImageView` back to false.

```
ImageView view = new ImageView();
view.mouseTransparentProperty().addListener((observable, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    if (newVal) {
        view.setMouseTransparent(false);
    }
});
```

Since you aren't using CSS to change the image based on hover/armed state this shouldn't cause the problems related to the bug. I'd be cautious, though; just in case.

---

A better workaround, mentioned by @fabian, is to wrap the `ImageView` in some other `Node` (e.g. a `Pane`).

```
Label customLabel = new Label(labelText, new Pane(removeImageView));
```

This makes the graphic a `Pane` which means the special `ImageView` handling in `updateChildren()` doesn't take place.

Comment: I think you are right about the source of the problem. When I changed `removeImageView` to `Text removeImageView = new Text("X");`  the event handler responds as expected. +1 . I will amend my answer

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround to `ImageView` being Mouse Transparent (See [Slaw answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575905/3992939) ), is to handle the event on  `ImageView` parent (`Lable`) and re fire it :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PropegateEvent extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Image image = new Image("https://addons-media.operacdn.com/media/extensions/65/165965/1.1.0.0-rev1/icons/icon_64x64_6dd346d4c61d287ae74c612622d1353f.png");
        ImageView removeImageView = new ImageView(image);
        Label customLabel = new Label("rito", removeImageView);
        Pane root = new Pane(customLabel);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //handle mouse event click on label -  refire it as image view event:
        customLabel.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> removeImageView.fireEvent(event));
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        removeImageView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
              @Override
              public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Imageview Clicked");
                event.consume();
              }
            });
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this situation is to use `HBox`. Instead of passing `ImageView` to `Label`'s constructor set `ImageView` and `Label` as child nodes of `HBox`

```
ImageView removeImageView = new ImageView(image); 
Label customLabel = new Label("rito");
customLabel.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));


HBox hbox = new HBox(removeImageView,customLabel);
root.getChildren().add(hbox);

removeImageView.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            System.out.println("ImageView clicked");
        });


customLabel.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            System.out.println("Lable clicked");
        });
```