# setOnMouseEntered not Working for ImageView in ListView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

i have a problem with setOnMouseEntered on JavaFx for ImageViews.
I'm trying to change the brightness of ImageViews placed in a Listview with ColorAdjust. The effect itself works for ImageViews that are not in the ListView.

I guess that only the ListView triggers the setOnMouseEntered, but not the ImageViews, which is my goal.
The same problem is caused by the hover effects of the ImageViews, which are not triggered as soon as they are in a ListView.

fxml:

```
 <ListView fx:id="cardsView" />
```

java-Code:

```
@FXML private ListView<ImageView> cardsView;
private ObservableMap<ImageView, Card> hCards;

@FXML
public void initialize() {
  hCards= FXCollections.observableHashMap();
  cardsView.getItems().setAll(hCards.keySet());
  hCards.addListener(
    (MapChangeListener<ImageView, Card>)
        change -> {
          cardsView.getItems().removeAll(change.getKey());
          if (change.wasAdded()) {
            cardsView.getItems().add(change.getKey());
          }
        });
  }
```

Later, for each of these ImageViews will be added:

```
private void addLightEffectOnMouseEntered(ImageView imageView) {
  imageView.setOnMouseEntered(
    t -> {
      ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
      colorAdjust.setBrightness(0.4);
      imageView.setEffect(colorAdjust);
    });
}
```

While debugging I figured out that things like css and the setOnMouseEntered are added correctly. So it seems to be somehow blocked by the ListView that the ChildNodes get the setOnMouseEntered or Hover effect instead of the ListView

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: I have added the main code :)

Comment: [mcve] is what @JaCo meant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is basically the same as this one: [Adding EventHandler To ImageView contained in a Label](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52574852/6395627). All `Cell` specializations, including `ListCell`, inherit from `Labeled` and all their default skins inherit from `LabeledSkinBase`, which is the source of your problem. As a fix to a bug (see other Q&A) when an `ImageView` is used as the graphic of a `Labeled` it is set to be mouse-transparent. Since the the `ImageView` is mouse-transparent your `MOUSE_ENTERED` handler can never be invoked for obvious reasons.

If you're not aware, the default cell factory of `ListView` returns a `ListCell` implementation that, when the item is an instance of `Node`, sets the `graphic` of the cell to the item. An easy fix is to use your own `ListCell` implementation that wraps the `ImageView` in another node, such as `Pane`. Here's an example:

```java
listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<>() {

  private final Pane imageViewContainer = new Pane();

  @Override
  protected void updateItem(ImageView item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty || item == null) {
      imageViewContainer.getChildren().clear();
      setGraphic(null);
    } else {
      imageViewContainer.getChildren().setAll(item);
      setGraphic(imageViewContainer);
    }
  }
});
```

This will prevent the `ImageView` from becoming mouse-transparent.

---

As a side note, it's typically not a good idea to use GUI objects (e.g. `ImageView`) as the model item of a `ListView` (or any other virtualized control). In this case, it may be an even worse idea since this set-up encourages holding every `Image` related to your application in memory simultaneously. Depending on how many images there are, as well as how large those images are, this can easily lead to an `OutOfMemoryError` or at least consume an unnecessary amount of your users' RAM.

You may want to consider using `Card` as the model item combined with a memory-constrained cache of `Image` objects (see [`WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) / [`SoftReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html), though you could also look for a third-party caching library). The `Card` class could hold the location of its associated image or the cache could derive the location based on the state of the `Card`.

You would still use an `ImageView` as the graphic of your `ListCell`, however, so you would still need to use the workaround mentioned above. What using a memory-constrained cache helps with is that, if a `Card` isn't being displayed in a `ListCell` then its associated `Image` possibly becomes eligible for garbage collection, thus reducing the memory demands of your application.

The cache also allows you to use the same `Image` everywhere in your application (the same `Image` can be shared between multiple `ImageView`s) and means you don't always load a new `Image` when a particular one is needed (as it could still be in memory when requested). In other words, the typical functionality provided by any cache.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you very much.
For others who want to use the code above - 
update.updateItem(item, empty); must be
super.updateItem(item, empty);